# why immutablejs documentation of indexOf is incomplete?

Tags: immutable.js

I´m using immutablejs, when I need to update a map object inside a list I do something like this:

```
myImmutableList.update(
           myImmutableList.findIndex( (item)=> item.get("_id") === action.payload), 
           (item)=> item.update('someAttr', value => !value)
  )
```

This works fine, my problem is with the documentation, it says:

indexOf()

Returns the first index at which a given value can be found in the Collection, or -1 if it is not present.

```
indexOf(searchValue: T): number
```

Where does it say that searchValue is a function  and how to use it?

Am I missing something in the docs?

I knew how to use it because I read the solution here in stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the function `findIndex` and you're looking at the documentation for the function `indexOf`.

Comment: I feel like Homer Simpson. Thanks a lot.